# Sending Devise mail via ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-activejob

in one of our apps we have a running ActiveJob / Sidekiq / ActionMailer setup which is working fine. As it's a booking app we send confirmations to users successfully through this setupo.

We're experiencing difficulties trying to get Devise sending mails on user actions (registration, password_reset, etc.) via ActiveJob.

I've did override the default behavior of notification sending within my `User` model like so:

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

#### Update

I've come a step closer. I added a queue Devise pushed it's job to which was missing (`XXX_default_mailer_queue) in`config/sidekiq.yml`. Now Devise successfully pushes jobs to the Sidekiq queue. But unfortunately still no mails become sent, Job execution times are far below 1s:

```
ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-fa4bccc79be489f098c7f5ef INFO: done: 0.415
```

If i switch to `devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_now` the proper email gets rendered but not sent either.
As I said, our Mail setup is working apart from Devise which is why I assume it to be a Devise specific problem somewhere

What does Devise do here? How can I debug the process? Normally I would jump somewhere in my job or mailer classes but there are none...

best, Andi

Comment: What kind of error or wrong behavior are you having? I recommend you to give more details to your question.

Comment: Sorry hernanvicente, you're right. Was a little desparate after hours of meaningless picking around. I've updated the answer, hope its more specific now

Comment: Have you found the answer